# Is there something like RequestLocal (like ThreadLocal)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, thread-local-storage, uicontrolstate

In C# there is a class [ThreadLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=netframework-4.7.2). You can use it to define a static field that only exist within the scope of a thread.

I am looking for something similar for use in an ASP Custom Control. I need to define a static field that is shared between all instances of this control, within the scope of a request.

Does there exist something out of the box for it?

Comment: `HttpContext.Items`?

Comment: You can make that the answer, it indeed is as simple as that. I was not aware that property did exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HttpContext.Items` dictionary that is associated with each request.

In ASCX code, for example:

```
this.Context.Items.Add("key", value);
```

See [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/ms972109(v=msdn.10)#and-now-for-something-really-wonderful-contextitems)